# Comparing two rows of numbers

Tags: r

I'm interested in writing a code that enables me to compare two rows of numbers that can also tell me if any numbers are missing from the second row.

Would anybody be able to help me get started or does anybody already have that kind of code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should provide sample data so that people can work with it, as well as an example of the result that you're looking for to check our results.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I honestly just started working with R as a hobby and i'm still not very good at it. I was thinking of comparing the two rows of numbers as matrices. A<-matrix(c(210,211,212,213),2)
B<-matrix(c(210,211,212),2)

Comment: the two rows have 1 number that they don't share. I was wondering how I could compare the two and make the code tell me what difference there is between the rows. In the instance above it should tell me that 213 is missing.

Comment: You want intersect  and oposite of intersect like this : https://www.r-bloggers.com/outersect-the-opposite-of-rs-intersect-function/ ?

Answer (score 1):

Given the data example that you provided in the comments, in which you have two matrices of equal dimensions:

```
A <- matrix(c(210, 211, 212, 213), 2)
B <- matrix(c(210, 211, 212, 214), 2)
```

You can check the differences merely doing this (with the `FALSE` being the values that are not equal:

```
A == B

##      [,1]  [,2]
## [1,] TRUE  TRUE
## [2,] TRUE FALSE
```

If you want to know where the difference is, you can do this (notice that a matrix is a special kind of vector, so you get just one index):

```
which(A != B)

## 4
```

Then, if you want to know what are the values in `A` and `B` that differ, you can do:

```
A[which(A != B)]

## 213

B[which(A != B)]

## 214
```

And you could subtract both lines if you want the actual difference in value:

```
A[which(A != B)] - B[which(A != B)]

## -1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) You have been a gret help. Hope you have a nice day.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Please mark the answer as correct so that others can find it!